# Where do I place free functions in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

I have several C++ functions that do not require any class attributes, and can be implemented as non-member functions. However, I am wondering how to implement these. I have read that it is NOT a good idea to create a "free function" or "utility" class and declare each function as static, as this creates issues with static linking. Do I implement such functions in a header file, or follow a header/source style similar to C++ classes? Or is there another alternative that is simpler?

I have included skeleton code of the class functions + free functions as an example of what I'm working with.

```
Layer::Layer(){
    // Layer attributes
}

Layer::FeedForward(){
    // Manipulates layer attribute values
}

// Free Function
Vector3DtoMatrix(vector<vector<vector<double> > > input3DVector){
    // Convert Vector to Matrix
}

// Free Function
MatrixTo3DVector(arma::mat inputMatrix){
    // Convert Matrix to Vector
}
```

Comment: "I have read that it is NOT a good idea to create a "free function""  - where did you read this? It is a very good idea to create free functions - in fact you should prefer them.

Comment: Your functions (other than the constructor `Layer::Layer`) are all missing return types.

Comment: Member and free functions are treated in exactly the same way by every linker I've seen, so I don't know what linking issues you're thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A utility class containing just static members is a bad idea not because of any linking issues (what issues?), but because there's no need for it.  If you really do want a scope around them for some reason, a `namespace`, not a `class`, would be the proper solution.

Just declare your free functions in a header file and implement them in a source file.

```
// Header file
arma::mat Vector3DtoMatrix(vector<vector<vector<double> > > input3DVector);

// Source file
arma::mat Vector3DtoMatrix(vector<vector<vector<double> > > input3DVector)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a namespace. Then the free functions are members of the namespace.

Note that because of C++ syntax, you often want a "friend" function instead of a member when a function like add() naturally operates on two equal objects. Also C++ does not allow you to create non-privileged members that are restricted to a classe's public interface, other than via inheritance, so again you want free functions here.

Comment: _"you often want a "friend" function"_ No, you don't want that!